# why won't this game start, it's looping

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

i have gone over every inch of this code i can not find out what is causing it to go into a loop. once i press key to start it plays the start noise and then it goes to the end screen and says press key to play again and i press it and it goes to start the game and plays the soung and one tick of the game and says game over.

```
import pygame, random, sys
from pygame.locals import *

WINDOWWIDTH = 600
WINDOWHEIGHT = 600
TEXTCOLOR = (255, 255, 255)
BGC = (0, 0, 0)
FPS = 80
PLAYERMOVERATE = 5
countBy = 10

def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def waitForPlayerToPressKey():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    terminate()
                return

def playerHasHitShoot(playerRect, shoot):
    if playerRect.colliderect(shoot):
        return True
    return False

def baddieHasHitShoot(baddieRect, shoot):
    if baddieRect.colliderect(shoot):
        return True
    return False

def drawText(text, font, surface, x, y):
    textobj = font.render(text, 1, TEXTCOLOR)
    textrect = textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft = (x, y)
    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)

def fire(shoot):
    shootRect.topleft = ((playerRect / 2), 101)
    shootRect.move_ip(5, 1)

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None,48)
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Mothers Day')
pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load('gameicon.gif'))

gameStartSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('gamestart.wav')
gameOverSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('gamestart.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.load('background.wav')

playerImage = pygame.image.load('starship.bmp')
playerRect = playerImage.get_rect()
baddieImage = pygame.image.load('enemy.bmp')
baddieRect = baddieImage.get_rect()
shootImage = pygame.image.load('shoot.bmp')
shootRect = shootImage.get_rect()


drawText('Star Trek', font, screen, (WINDOWWIDTH / 2.5), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
drawText('Press a key to start.', font, screen, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3.75) - 30, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
pygame.display.update()
waitForPlayerToPressKey()


topScore = 10000
while True:

    score = 10000
    playerRect.topleft = (0, 100)
    baddieRect.topright = (600, 100)
    moveUp = moveDown = False
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)

    while True:
        score -= countBy
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_UP:
                    moveDown = False
                    moveUp = True
                if event.key == ord(' '):
                    fire
                if event.key == K_DOWN:
                    moveUp = False
                    moveDown = True

            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == ord(' '):
                    fire
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        terminate()
                if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                    moveUp = False
                if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                    moveDown = False


        if moveUp and playerRect.top > 0:
            playerRect.move_ip(0, -1 * PLAYERMOVERATE)
        if moveDown and playerRect.bottom < WINDOWHEIGHT:
            playerRect.move_ip(0, PLAYERMOVERATE)


        drawText('Score: %s' % (score), font, screen, 10, 0)
        drawText('Top Score: %s' % (topScore), font, screen, 10, 40)

        screen.blit(playerImage, playerRect)
        screen.blit(shootImage, shootRect)
        screen.blit(baddieImage, baddieRect)
        pygame.display.update()


        if playerHasHitShoot(playerRect, baddieRect):
            score = 0 
        break

        if baddieHasHitShoot(baddieRect, shoot):
            if score > topScore:
                score = topscore
            break
        mainClock.tick(FPS)

    sb = pygame.image.load('sb.png')
    screen.blit(sb, (600, 600))
    screen.fill(BGC)        
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    gameOverSound.play()
    drawText('GAME OVER', font, screen, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
    drawText('Press a key to play again.', font, screen, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 80, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
    pygame.display.update()
    waitForPlayerToPressKey()
    gameOverSound.stop()
```

Comment: i am modeling after another code that works, and even so how would i go about making the code work without the `while True`

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is wrong with the font](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23575793/what-is-wrong-with-the-font)

Comment: that was about a problem with my font not loading this is a problem with my start looping to my end. this is the same code because i have used this code to ask questions on the what is wrong with the font

Comment: the possible duplicate is **NOT** the awnser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if playerHasHitShoot(playerRect, baddieRect):
    score = 0 
break
```

That `break` will be hit every frame, and immediately go to the 'Game Over' section at the end. I'm guessing you only intended this to happen if `playerHasHitShoot` returned true? If so:

```
if playerHasHitShoot(playerRect, baddieRect):
    score = 0 
    break
```

It's less clear what the following bit (that's currently never running) is meant to do, but you should check and make sure all your conditional paths are correct:

```
if baddieHasHitShoot(baddieRect, shoot):
    if score > topScore:
        score = topscore
    break
```